# Can't get value from useState when this.state works

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, use-effect, react-functional-component, use-state

I am trying to create a todo-list using data from a firebase database. In the following code, it runs a function called `handleChange`, which runs when user checks or unchecks a box. Depending if it is checked or not & checkbox's ID, it flips from true or false when clicked. I tried replicating this [tutorial](https://scrimba.com/p/p7P5Hd/cgDqBHP) in REACT & Google Firebase with no luck.

```
    const [allTodos, setTodos] = useState([])  
    useEffect(() => {
        const database = firebase.database().ref();
        database.on("value", logData)  
    }, []) 

    function logData(rowData) {    
        setTodos(rowData.val())
    } 
    function handleChange(id) {
        console.log(id);
        setTodos(prevState => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.allTodos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
                return todo
            })
            return {
                allTodos: updatedTodos
            }

        })   
    }
```

Giving this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

```
  17 | function handleChange(id) {
  18 |     console.log(id);
  19 |     setTodos(prevState => {
> 20 |         const updatedTodos = prevState.allTodos.map(todo => {
     | ^  21 |             if (todo.id === id) {
  22 |                 todo.completed = !todo.completed
  23 |             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure from code what is happening with the state and when change handler is called, but for sure the state does not have any `allTodos` at `handle change` time, and it is better to update state regardless of prevState. let's separate the state update as follow and see what happens

```
const updatedTodos = allTodos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
            });
 setTodos(updatedTodos);
```

Comment: Interesting, what if I wanted to remember the previous state? For example, if I had a function that increases a variable by +1 when a button is clicked.

Comment: The same approach, your state is containing something lets say initially `0` then `addByOne` handler is called, so what you want to do is to `0+1`, so you do not need to deconstruct 0 as `prevState`, as your current state is 0, so basically `setState(state+1);`

Answer (score 0):

`prevState.allTodos` is undefined because `prevState` is not an object with an `allTodos` property... `prevState` itself is `allTodos`.

Try this:

```
    const [allTodos, setTodos] = useState([])  
    useEffect(() => {
        const database = firebase.database().ref();
        database.on("value", logData)  
    }, []) 

    function logData(rowData) {    
        setTodos(rowData.val())
    } 
    function handleChange(id) {
        console.log(id);
        setTodos(prevTodos => {
            const updatedTodos = prevTodos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed
                }
                return todo
            })
            return updatedTodos // <-- return the todos, not an object
        })   
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is returning `updatedTodos`, but it's not setting `allTodos` = `updatedTodos`.

Comment: Notice that I'm using the functional version of `setTodos`. The value that's returned from that function gets set as the new `allTodos` value. See here for documentation on functional `useState`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates